# Finding the equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

I am currently working on a problem where a particle of mass $m$ can move along the x-axis with no friction. The particle is moving in a gravitational field and the potential energy is given by:

$$E_{pot(x)}=-2Cm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(ab)^2}}$$

I want to find the equation of motion for this particle by using the law of conservation of energy.

$$E_{pot(x)}+E_{kin(\dot{x})}=constant$$

$$\iff -2Cm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(ab)^2}}+\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^2=constant$$

I didn't know how to deal with the constant term so I just used the fact that the derivative of any constant is $0$ and differentiated both sides.

$$\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-2Cm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(ab)^2}})+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^2)=0$$

$$\iff Cm\frac{2x\color{red}{\dot{x}}}{(\sqrt{x^2+(ab)^2})^3}+m\dot{x}\color{red}{\ddot{x}}=0$$

Question 1: Am I differentiating correctly here? I am not sure if I have to implicitly differentiate $x$ and $\dot{x}$

Question 2: Does my approach even make sense or am I just wasting my time here?

Edit:

$$m\dot{x}\space (\ddot{x}+\frac{C}{(x^2+(ab)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}x)=0$$

$$\iff \ddot{x}+\frac{C}{(x^2+(ab)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}x=0$$

Comment: How do you get $\dot{x}$ in the first term if you are taking the derivatives of $x$?

Comment: @KyleKanos I differentiated $x^2$ under the square root. This is why I was asking if I need to implicitly differentiate because then I would get $2x\cdot \dot{x}$

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What is $\dot{x}$?

Comment: I would say that is the velocity.

Comment: So how do you get a *velocity* ($dx/dt$) when taking the derivative with respect to *space*?

Comment: Woops, you're right that makes no sense. I should be taking the derivative with respect to time then.

Comment: So I basically already took the derivative with respect to time even though I indicated that I would be taking it with respect to space right?

Comment: Yes, you did take the derivative w/ respect to time in the work above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added an "answer" to my opening post. Does my equation of motion make sense? Just in general, does an equation of motion have to have some sort of format? I remember when we did harmonic oscillations that all of them seemed to be in form $\ddot{x}+Cx=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to take any time derivatives here. Since the energy, $E$, is a constant, you only need to know it at one moment in time (say at t=0 as an initial condition), and you know it at all other times. Thus, just solve for $\dot{x}(t)$ in terms of the other quantities ($x,E,...)$ in the second equation that you have to get the equation of motion. Like all differential equations, you have to supply initial conditions to get the particular solution or trajectory.

Comment: Thanks. So I don't need the second derivative in my equation at all? I always thought they have to be in the form $\ddot{x}+Cx=0$

Comment: An equation of motion is really just any equation involving the trajectory x(t) and its derivatives.

Comment: But when you say "its derivatives", does it have to be all of them ($\ddot{x}(t), \dot{x}(t)$) or can it be just the first derivative $\dot{x}(t)$

Comment: It can just be the first one. Really any combination is an equation of motion.